# Microsoft Project REAL - SSAS connection

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I am setting up Microsoft Project REAL with SQL Server 2008 R2.

After attaching the relational database and creating the olap cube, I am unable to process it because it is reporting an OLE DB connection faliure.

I am able to connect my own user to both, but processing under my user yields the same result.

Which users need to be running the Analysis Services and is there an impersonation mode I should be using?

SQL Server Agent under local service
Analysis services under local service

Comment: Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DataSourceID', Name of 'DataSourceName'. 
Either the 'UserName' user does not have permission to access the 'DataSourceName' object, or the object does not exist.

Comment: I granted the Full Control permission to a new role. Seems to be processing only a portion of the cube. Only dimensions process, but at least connection is now up and running.

Comment: did you test the connection string of data source? which impersanation mode are you using? Try with Windows Authentication.

Comment: the issue is resolved. The connection string is OK, some partitions in Project REAL are invalid, so after removing them a full process completes with success. thanks for your help!